# Accessibility disabled for app in Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks

After upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 and running my app (which executes various AppleScripts as part of its execution) I get a dialog that the app has to be specifically enabled via the System Preferences Security/Privacy screen. So I do this and the app then functions properly.

However, when I recompile and build the app, it will no longer execute the AppleScripts and does not show the dialog. When I look in the System Preferences Security/Privacy I see that my app is still listed there but has been disabled (i.e. checkbox reset).

BY trial and error, I have found the following:

If you change the Bundle Version string in the apps info.plist and rebuild the app even without making any other changes such as code, etc this will happen; it will be disabled from accessibility.

If you make all kinds of changes to the app (code, resources, etc) but do not change the Bundle Version string in info.plist, it will still be allowed to have accessibility access.

My question is: is there a way to circumvent disabling after rebuilding?

Comment: Have the same issue.  Whenever I re-run my app, it becomes disabled in Security > Privacy.

It seems like the `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` call resets it for some reason.

Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: :+1: I have the same problem myself.